# Plane curve in tropical geometry with "multiplicative inverse"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tropical-geometry

I am new to tropical geometry with addition is the $\max$ and multiplication  the usually $+$ and I am trying to understand the translation of polynomials from the tropical setting to the classical setting. For example the abstract structure
$$a\odot x^2\oplus b\odot x\oplus c= \max\lbrace 2x+a,x+b,c\rbrace$$
is clear but I am struggeling with the inverse way, if there is the multiplicative inverse involved for the reals. For example what is in tropical notation

$$p(x,y)=2\max\lbrace x,y\rbrace-(x+y)=\max\lbrace x,y\rbrace+\max\lbrace -x,-y\rbrace=?$$

I do not manage to resolve the negative signs here. Intuitively, it should be the analog of

$$q(x,y)=\frac{2(x+y)}{xy}$$
but this is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tropical multiplication is nothing else than the usual addition, it forms an abelian group. In consequence, each element possesses an inverse element with respect to multiplication, namely $x^{\odot-1} = -x$. N.B. : more generally, a tropical power can be defined as $x^{\odot n} = x \odot \ldots \odot x = n \cdot x$. You might introduce a new symbol, such as a circled division, in order to represent the tropical division.

Let's work on the first part of $p(x,y)$; one has :
$$
p_1(x,y) := 2\max(x,y) = (x \oplus y)^{\odot2} = (x \oplus y) \odot (x \oplus y) = x^{\odot2} \oplus (x \odot y) \oplus (y \odot x) \oplus y^{\odot2}
$$
where we used the distributivity of tropical multiplication over tropical addition. Now, the middle expression with the mixed products can be simplified thanks to the commutativity of tropical multiplication, i.e. $x \odot y = y \odot x$, as well as the idempotency of tropical addition, i.e. $a \oplus a = \max(a,a) = a$, so that
$$
2\max(x,y) = x^{\odot2} \oplus (x \odot y) \oplus y^{\odot2}
$$

The second part of $p(x,y)$ is simply translated as $p_2(x,y) := -(x+y) = (x \odot y)^{\odot-1} = x^{\odot-1} \odot y^{\odot-1}$. It is then gathered together with the first part of $p(x,y)$ as follows :
$$
p = p_1 + p_2 = p_1 \odot p_2 
  = \left(x^{\odot2} \oplus (x \odot y) \oplus y^{\odot2}\right) \odot x^{\odot-1} \odot y^{\odot-1} 
  = (x \odot y^{\odot-1}) \oplus 0 \oplus (x^{\odot-1} \odot y),
$$
where we used the distibutivity of $\odot$ over $\oplus$ again and the fact that $0$ is the identity element of $\odot$. The last expression can be considered as a standard bivariate tropical (Laurent) polynomial, which is indeed the tropical analog of $\frac{(x+y)^2}{xy} = xy^{-1} + 1 + x^{-1}y$.

Comment: Great, thank you! How would I go about drawing a planar tropical curve associated to $p=(x\odot y^{\odot -1 })\oplus 0\oplus (x^{\odot -1 }\odot y)$ ? For polynomials it is well explained but how does it work for Laurent polynomials?

Comment: @Jfischer  I must admit I am not able to answer; I didn't know tropical geometry before and I learnt expressly the basic rules of this algebra in order to provide answer to your post.